# Fold and side Pot Questions?

Tags: rules, all-in, fold-equity

FLOP:
A All-in 500
B Call 500
C Call 500
(Side pot A-B-C = 1500)
TURN:
B Raise to 1000
C Call 1000
(side pot B-C 2000)
RIVER:
B Raise 2000
C Fold

My question is:

imagine that
C has the best hand (fold on the river - 1500 on the pot)
A has the second best hand (all in in the flop 500 on the pot)
B has the worst hand

I think the natural decision is:
Player A wins the side pot of 1500
Player C the side pot of 2000)

BUT...

It's not weird that Player A, can win the side pot of 1500, when he contributed with 500,
but Player C that gets better hand than A and contributed with 1500 to the pot cannot win anything because he folded?.... My question is, player C folded against player B, not against player A (and payed much more money) - so dont you think it would be fair that player B can be as eligible as player A to win the side pot of 1500??
PS(Of course B cannot win the side pot of 2000 B-C from the turn, because he folded against C, so the best hands doesn't matter, its normal)

What do you think?
I think that it should be logical to say that player B didnt folded against player A, so everything that is accessible to player A should be accessible to player B, because he always made a call to player A and never folded against him.... I think the logic of poker is: to win to some other player you need to have one of this: 1) better hand or 2) invest more money and make other player fold. Its weird to see a player to invest less money and have weaker hand to win more than someone thant invested more money and had better hand....

Comment: Your question is still pretty unclear.

Comment: If you could format this question more clearly, I'm sure it would get some more responses. I agree with Andrew, the hand example is not very clear. There are plenty of example of well formatted hands on this site.